# How to write AJAX code to print PHP error to alert() box?

Tags: mysql, ajax, pdo

This was originally a question about PHP, I have edited the PHP question as follows:

The AJAX code, which I found on this site, is intended to put error messages in an alert box which worked up until now.  Sorry if some mistakes are obvious, just been working on this too much.

PHP:

```
<?php
include 'pdo_connect.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


if ($uname = isset($_POST['uname']) ? $_POST['uname'] : ''){
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', USER, PASS);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = :uname';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":uname",$uname, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($uname));

$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 0);
echo json_encode($rows);
echo json_encode("It works!");

$stmt->execute();



$conn = null;
$query = null;
}
?>
```

AJAX:

```
function checkName() {
$.ajax({
url: "check_name.php",
data: {uname: $('#uname').val(), upassword: $('#upassword').val()},
type: "POST",
dataType:"text"
})
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
};

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
oReq.onload = function() {

    alert(this.responseText); 
};
oReq.open("post", "check_name.php", true);

oReq.send();

};
```

This is exactly how my code looks in the JavaScript file.  I have several other functions in the file so I don't think my JavaScript file is to blame.

Comment: What about checking a tutorial first?

Comment: You are mixing named parameters with ?

Comment: I changed methods so many times I must have mixed those up - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sth = $conn->prepare($stmt);
```

before

```
$stmt->bindParam(':uname', $uname, PDO::PARAM_STRING);
```

Additionally, use the following code after you execute() the query to dump PDO error data if an error is present (not tested, but the gist is correct. See [PDOStatement::errorCode()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php) and [PDOStatement::errorInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php))

```
if($stmt->errorCode() !== "00000") {
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo())
}
```

Comment: There is no point in checking errorInfo if exception mode is enabled

Comment: You're right. Also, I think you're binding it incorrectly. You don't have a ':uname' parameter in your query. Replace your bind code with this and give it a try: $stmt->bindParam(1, $uname, PDO::PARAM_STRING);

Comment: Still no errors, I feel like this is something obvious but don't have enough experience to put my finger on it - thank you.

Comment: As per documentation if you are using question mark place holder. Bind like this: 
`$sth->bindParam(1, $uname, PDO::PARAM_STRING, strlen($uname));`

Comment: Alright, in firebug this gives an error for undefined class constant PARAM_STRING which I thin kis PARAM_STR - and javascript is sending values btw.  I will look into documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

This:

`$stmt = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = ?';`

is a string. It does not have a method called `bindParam`. You need to prepare the statement first, and then bind variables to it like this:

```
$query= 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $uname);
```

This returns an object of type `PDOStatement` that has a `bindParam` method which you can call

If you want to use ':uname' you need to specify it in the query. If you use question marks placeholders you must use numbers in `bindParam`. With a text placeholder you can do it like this:

```
$query= 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = :uname';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':uname', $uname);
```

Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) tutorial on PHP PDO Prepared statements for more.

Comment: That also returned no error.  I think though since Firebug indicates there is nothing returned from the server it is either my query is wrong or the ajax call is incorrect.

Comment: @user6571726 Have you checked the server's error log?

Comment: yes, finally, it said `cannot pass parameter by reference`, referring to `parameter 2` of `$stmt->bindParam($uname, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($uname));`

Comment: @user6571726 Try `bindValue(1, $uname);`. If it fails there is something wrong with your AJAX request and `$uname` ends up `null`

Comment: I think you are right, I'm also a beginner at ajax.